# How Android View Hierarchies work

Tags: android-2.1-eclair

I have a WebView that I would like to expand to fullscreen. The user will interact with it, so it needs to maintain some sort of state when it expands. The ideal process is this:

```
- Remove WebView from its parent
- Put WebView at the top of the current View hierarchy with `FILL_PARENT` for width and height
```

Later, I will need the put the WebView back:

```
- Remove WebView from top of the hierarchy
- Restore the old hierarchy
- Put WebView back where it was with its previous setting for width and height
```

I know about `getRootView`, but I don't know how to use it. What's a `DecorView`?

If anyone has some sample code to accomplish the expanding and collapsing behavior I've described above, I'd be really grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the root view of the `DecorView`:

```
ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) webView.getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View rootview = parentViewGroup.getChildAt(0);
```

Remove that root view:

```
parentViewGroup.removeViewAt(0);
```

Remove the `WebView` from its parent:

```
View webViewParent = (View) webView.getParent();
webViewParent.removeView(webView);
```

Put the `WebView` at the top of the view hierarchy:

```
parentViewGroup.addView(webView, 0, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Use your `rootview` reference to undo the expansion.

The only thing is: I don't know how you're going to restore the layout parameters for `rootview`.